# How to quickly find a subset of linearly independent vectors given a list of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

As stated in the title, are there any "shortcuts" to doing so? I know that the typical approach is to just solve the rref of the matrix (formed by the vectors in the given set) and the vectors with 1s in the pivot columns are the ones that are lin. ind.

I wanted to see if it was possible to avoid doing "busy work" and solve this doing as little calculations as possible. The following describes my thought process throughout the problem:

---

> Let $\mathsf W$ denote the subspace of $\mathsf R^5$ consisting of all the vectors having coordinates that sum to zero. The vectors
>   $$\begin{align}
> u_1 &= (2,-3,4,-5,2), & u_2 &= (-6,9,-12,15,-6),\\
> u_3 &= (3,-2,7,-9,1), & u_4 &= (2,-8,2,-2,6),\\
> u_5 &=(-1,1,2,1,-3), & u_6 &= (0,-3,-18,9,12),\\
> u_7 &= (1,0,-2,3,-2), & u_8 &= (2,-1,1-9,7)
> \end{align}$$
>    generate $\mathsf W$. Find a subset of the set $\{u_1, u_2,...,u_8\}$ that is a basis for $\mathsf W$.

Here in the question , I immediately knew vectors $u_6$ and $u_7$ were linearly  independent ($u_6$ has $0$ in col $1$ while $u_7$ has a non-zero number in that col and $u_6$ has a non-zero number in col 2 while $u_7$ has in 0 in that col so that there would never be a linear combination that makes them equal)

Now because it's given that $W$ is a subspace of $R^5$, that means that at most we'd need $3$ more vectors to find a basis from the given set. Upon inspection, I noticed that $u_2$ was a scalar multiple of $u_1$ so I knew that $u_2$ wasn't linearly independent. This leaves $\{u_1, u_3, u_4, u_5, u_8\}$ for me to choose from.

This is where i had a bit of trouble and decided to look at the solution: "$\{u_1, u_3, u_6, u_7\}$ is a basis for $W$ (the answer here will not be unique)"

---

After looking at the answer, I'm still having trouble figuring out what I should've done to get $u_1$ and $u_3$ without any calculations. The main thing i notice is that $u_1$, $u_4$, and $u_8$ all have $2$ for their first entries while $u_3$ and $u_5$ have $3$ and $-1$, respectively (not sure if that is relevant but wanted to point that out in case). The answer key did specify that the answer they provided was not unique, so i'm assuming that means there's at least another set of vectors that form a basis for $W$ (ie, $\{u', u'', u_6, u_7\}$ where $u'$ and $u''$ would be the other possible choice(s) of vectors from $\{u_1, u_3, u_4, u_5, u_8\}$)

Is there a "shortcut" I can use (kind of like the "concept" used to immediately figure out u6 and u7 were linearly  independent) or would I have to reduce $u_1,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_8$ to rref to find the other two linearly independent vectors?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: honestly you'd probably be using some form of rref or linear combination.

Comment: $\{u_2,u_3,u_6,u_7\}$ is another possibility. Can you see why?